# How can embed wordpress blog in Codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, phpbb

How can  integrate wordpress blog and phpbb forum in codeigniter. These three should have a common login. Anybody can help me?

Comment: are you trying to create a black hole ? You are trying to combine something bad with something horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you could use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) for that. The thing with common login would be a bit harder to do. You would have to modify the code of the blog or the forum (or of both). Than you could create a seperate user table in your database which would contain the common logins.

If you don't manage to embed PhpBB in CI, you could also give [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) a try, which is easy to use with iframes.

Comment: My folder structer
App(codeigniter)
Index.php(codeigniter)
--------
Blog (WP all the wp files are included her )
Ie. Can access  wp blog 
Mysite.com/blog .it is working fine.The prblem is now user need to login seperatly for wp even if he is logged in at CI

Comment: I don't know much about the code of those two projects, but somewhere it is checking internally if the user is already logged in or not. So you would have to find this part of code and change it with some other code written by yourself. Eventually there may be a plugin or something like that which could help you. Otherwise try to use a WP plugin which creates a forum, than you would already have the login problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.wp-united.com/ to integrate the phpBB and WordPress logins, and then you can use the phpBB login in CodeIgniter.

I'm going to shamelessly promote my own tutorial on using phpBB logins from outside the phpBB codebase: http://lynxphp.com/php/integrating-phpbb-sessions/ I've never used WP-United, so I can't help you there, but I've heard that it's pretty good.